# How to find closest line of polygon

Tags: postgis, geoserver, arcgis-server, oracle-spatial

I have polygon layers on my ArcGIS Server and Geoserver. I need to find the closest line length of the polygon.

[image]

For example p(x1,x1) will get the L2 length and p(x2,y2) will get the L4 length.

1. Can I do this with ArcGIS geometry services?
2. Can I do this via PostGIS or Oracle Spatial functions?

Comment: You have **three** questions in this Question, two too many. Please edit the question to focus on **one** software environment, with exact version details.

Comment: what do you mean p(x1,y1) will get the l2 length? the distance between p(x1,y1) and L2? or the lenght of the segment L2 on the polygon?

Comment: I think the OP wants the *segment* L4. It remains unclear if the segments have been stored separately, or whether that is part of the problem set as well.

Comment: @Vince should the poster copy-paste this question into three separate questions, with only the software environment changed?  Does this site now have a restriction on being flexible with your tools?

Comment: It would be best to focus the question to the point in can be answered in one environment,  then review that answer before asking a variant question. Having too many questions open before it's obvious the root question is answerable only means more dowvotes and editing. Having too many mutually exclusive tools at play isn't flexibility, it's inability to focus.

Comment: @Vince.  Indeed.  Best to just close it and not get an answer for any tool.

Comment: @dbaston Asking a question for multiple different software packages makes the question too broad.  If an answer is required for all then yes they should be asked separately.  Asking for them all in one question means there could be multiple correct answers, but only one can be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: My datas are stored two different database and two different gis server (arcgis, geoserver) Any of solution will solve my solution. Nobody answered questioned but everyone says question seperation. If this question is not about this platform I will delete it.